# I have Java 8. An app wants Java 6 (legacy one). Can I avoid that?

Tags: java

My government made a Java app to submit tax documents.

That app, it's actually a very outdated version of Eclipse.

When I run this ugly mess, I get a dialog that prompts me to install Java SE 6 (Legacy) from Apple.

I'd like to avoid that, for security issues, and also because I don't want to mess my Java installation

How could I force it to run on my Java 8 jvm?

The app is this: https://telematici.agenziaentrate.gov.it/Main/Desktop.jsp

Comment: It doesn't mess with your Java installation, it installs as a legacy framework for certain applications. AFAIK, there is no workaround: the app you need to run requires Java SE 6 to run.

Comment: last time i did that, i spent hours to fix the mess the java installer did. If there's a way to edit some plist to let it use the newer java... after all their website says it want java 1.7, not 1.6

Comment: I used to have to do this to run an old version of Adobe stuff. It installs a set of "legacy components", it does not replace your Java 8 install. You installed this? https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US

Comment: Java 6 is past its end of life by several years - I would ask the website supplier how to get it.

Comment: As it says you need 1.7 rather than 1.6 then I would download 1.7 JDH from Oracle and install that - the chnage the eclipse.ini file touse that Java. Java >= 1.7 can have several versions installed at once.

Comment: Sounds like it is a 32-bit Eclipse platform app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely can not avoid this. The app you needs to use is built to run on the Java SE 6 framework. Java 8 is not backwards compatible, so you cannot "force" this app to run on Java 8. The only way to avoid installing the Java 6 SE components is if you can somehow avoid using this particular app.

You do **not** want to install using the Java installer found on the Oracle website. This will result in you having multiple copies of Java on your system, and it will be a mess.

Follow the link in the notice you get, (I think it's this https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US) it will take you to an Apple download of a very specific set of "Java SE 6 Legacy runtime components". This can exist alongside your Java 8 installation and is used by certain outdated software (I used to have to install this to use an older version of Adobe Creative Suite before I updated to the CC version).

** I admit I'm not 100% sure that the SE 6 Legacy components are compatible with Mojave, but I **think** that they are and that there was maybe a notice that Mojave would be the last compatible version of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Like most of the answers on the web around this message dialog, the answer from @Morgan Rodgers *might* be correct in the case that the application really does have a specific need for that ancient version of Java. However, for many applications, a current/modern version of Java will work just fine except that [they are wrongly configured](https://unfinishedbitness.info/2015/03/03/os-x-legacy-java-se-6-error-resolution/).

At least on Mavericks 10.9 through Catalina 10.15, you can edit the JVM capabilites to correctly reflect what your Java 10, 11 etc can do in this file:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<your modern java version>/Contents/Info.plist
```

You will need to replace the section around line 27 which looks like this:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>CommandLine</string>
    </array>
```

with the correct set of capabilities:

```
<key>JVMCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>JNI</string>
        <string>BundledApp</string>
        <string>WebStart</string>
        <string>Applets</string>
        <string>CommandLine</string>
    </array>
```

As [1](https://unfinishedbitness.info/2015/03/03/os-x-legacy-java-se-6-error-resolution/) mentions, the editing may need to be done via text editor using a temporary copy, which is moved back into place using sudo. *Once copied back, don't forget to check the timestamp and content of the updated file reflect your edit and reboot*.

Comment: I just noticed this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847411/to-open-eclipse-you-need-to-install-the-legacy-java-se-6-runtime)